# react-hook-form isDirty seems weird for me

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Today, I started to use react-hook-form and the **isDirty** variable seems quite weird for me.
It is always true although only the focus was given to any input elements.

I expect isDirty should be true only when value of input element changes. Is that normal in react-hook-form?

```
// I had to make workaround like this. but I am not sure if this is normal for everybody.
const closeForm = () => {
    const { dirtyFields } = form.formState
    const isReallyDirty = Object.keys(dirtyFields).length > 0

    if (isReallyDirty) {
        if (window.confirm("Discard the changes?")) {
            dispatch(closeItem())
        }
    } else {
        dispatch(closeItem())
    }
}
```

**UPDATE: I think this is a bug of react-hook-form?**
react-hook-form version 6.11.0

This happens only when React.forwardRef was used.

```
const TextareaBox = ({ ref, ...props }) => {
    const { errors, name } = props
    const { required, ...restProps } = props

    return (
        <Row>
            <Label {...props} columnSize={2} />
            <Col lg={10}>
                <textarea id={name} {...restProps} maxLength="200" rows="3" ref={ref} />
                <ErrorMessage className="errorMessage" errors={errors} name={name} as="p" />
            </Col>
        </Row>
    )
}

const TextareaBox = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const { errors, name } = props
    const { required, ...restProps } = props

    return (
        <Row>
            <Label {...props} columnSize={2} />
            <Col lg={10}>
                <textarea id={name} {...restProps} maxLength="200" rows="3" ref={ref} />
                <ErrorMessage className="errorMessage" errors={errors} name={name} as="p" />
            </Col>
        </Row>
    )
})
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I ended up solving it by checking length of **dirtyFields** property of the formState.

In react hook form, you may feel that **isDirty** behaves more like it is **isTouched**. But you have to pass the **defaultValue** to the input field because RHF needs a value to compare against as mentioned in the official documents.

[image]

Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Yes. I did the same to workaround.

Comment: what do you mean checking the length of dirtyfields?

Comment: My solution to this problem was the first bullet point: One has to pass _**all**_ default values.